# is there a way to make the list contain all of the indexes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying to make a list with all common possibilities of the words in known_in_lines list .
the problems is , however , because i'm using the "for loop" , every time "i" goes up one , the list will reset and therefor the code will end up with printing the last index of the list in lower case and stuff.
is there a way i can make all of the indexes of the list for into the function and be returned all together ? basically , can i make insensitive_string list outside of the function so that it wont reset the list every time i use the function ?

```
def case_insensitive(*texts) :
    insensitive_string = []
    for text in texts :
        insensitive_string.extend [text.lower(),text.upper(),text.capitalize()]
    return (insensitive_string)

known_in_lines = ["hello" ,
                 "hi" ,
                 "what's up" ,
                 "how are you doing" ,
                 "how was your day" ]

for i in range (0,len(known_in_lines)) :
    insensitive_string = case_insensitive(known_in_lines[i])

print (insensitive_string)
```

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: ...just to simplify the code: make it `for line in known_in_lines:` Isn't that just the problem of putting the `print` into the `for` loop?

Comment: [["hello","HELLO","Hello"],["hi","HI","Hi"],...]

Comment: mikuszefski , yea thats .... thats actually a pretty good idea . but yea , i tried it . it didnt work .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend the list inside the loop, but in fact that is exactly what the `case_insensitive` function does if you give it many arguments. Just do:

```
insensitive_string = case_insensitive(*known_in_lines)
```

You will get:

```
['hello', 'HELLO', 'Hello', 'hi', 'HI', 'Hi', "what's up", "WHAT'S UP", "What's up", 'how are you doing', 'HOW ARE YOU DOING', 'How are you doing', 'how was your day', 'HOW WAS YOUR DAY', 'How was your day']
```

Answer (score 1):

There were some syntactical issues with the extend method (now fixed), and the printout has been nested into the loop together with an iteration counter for visibility:

```
def case_insensitive(*texts):
    insensitive_string = []
    for text in texts:
        insensitive_string.extend([text.lower(),
                                   text.upper(),
                                   text.capitalize()
        ])
    return insensitive_string

known_in_lines = ["hello",
                  "hi",
                  "what's up",
                  "how are you doing",
                  "how was your day"
                  ]

for num, i in enumerate(range(len(known_in_lines))):
    insensitive_string = case_insensitive(known_in_lines[i])
    print(num)
    print (insensitive_string)

print(case_insensitive(*known_in_lines))
```

Produces:

```
0
['hello', 'HELLO', 'Hello']
1
['hi', 'HI', 'Hi']
2
["what's up", "WHAT'S UP", "What's up"]
3
['how are you doing', 'HOW ARE YOU DOING', 'How are you doing']
4
['how was your day', 'HOW WAS YOUR DAY', 'How was your day']

['hello', 'HELLO', 'Hello', 'hi', 'HI', 'Hi', "what's up", "WHAT'S UP", "What's up", 'how are you doing', 'HOW ARE YOU DOING', 'How are you doing', 'how was your day', 'HOW WAS YOUR DAY', 'How was your day']
```